# $a,b \in Z$, $a>b$ if and only if $a − b$ is a positive natural number.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, self-learning

> $a,b \in Z$, $a>b$ if and only if $a − b$ is a positive natural number (Terence Tao - Anlysis $1$ ex $4.1.7$). Note: Integer $x = n-m$ for some $n,m \in N$. Substraction was introduced as $x-y = x + (-y)$ where $x,y \in Z$. That is $x = n-m, y = d-k$ for some $n,m,d,k \in N$ and $-y = k-d$

take $a = x-y$, $b = c-d$ for any $x,y,c,d \in N$.

$a>b$ then $\exists m \in N, a = b+n$ => $x-y=c-d+n$

$a-b = (x-y)-(c-d) = (c-d+n)-(c-d) = (c-d+n)+(-(c-d))=(c-d+n)+(d-c)=(c-d+n)+(d-c - 0) = c-d+d-c-(n-0)=c-d-c-d-(n-0) = -(n-0)=-n$ so I get that $a-b$ is equal to negative number. Can you point out where I am wrong and how to solve the problem?

Comment: Just subtract/add b on both sides?

Comment: The equality $(c - d + n) + (d - c - 0) = c - d + d - c - (n - 0)$ is false.

Comment: If you fix the calculation mistake, you get $a - b = n$, which proves the if part. For the only if part, super gave you the answer.

Comment: @PeldePinda I am sorry, can you show me where is the mistake because I really struggle to see it? It should be c+(d-c) - (d+n + 0) = c+d-c - d+n = c+d+(d-c) + n?

Comment: Working out the brackets, the left side say $n$ and the right side $-n$. I am not quite sure what you are trying to do. You just get $c - d + n + d - c - 0 = c - c + d - d + n = n$.

Comment: @PeldePinda I see what you mean. Here c-d is a number (an integer) as well as d-c, which is reciprocal of it. The sum of two integers was defined as $(a-b) + (c-d) = (a+c) - (b+d)$ for some numbers $x = a-b$ and $y = c-d$, therefore I can't just open the brackets. I should have written that too. I am sorry.

Comment: Ok, but you still see that it is wrong the way you wrote it in the main post right? In that case say $(c - d + n) + (d - c - 0) = (c - d + n + 0) + (-c - (-d)) = (c - d) + (-c - (-d)) + n = (c + -c) - (d + (-d)) + n= 0 - 0 + n = n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that on one of the previous exercises I prooved quite a handy law: $x+(-x) = (-x)+x = 0, x \in Z$ (the proof was by contradiction).

Using that:

$(c-d) + n = (c-d)+(n-0) = (c+n)-(d+0) = (c+n)-d$ so far so good

$a-b = ((c+n)-d) - (c-d) = ((c+n)-d) + (-c - (-d))=(c+n+(-c)) - (d+(-d)) = (n+c+(-c)) - (d+(-d))$ since $n, c \in N$

$a-b=n+0-0=n-0=n$

The only part at this point in which I am not entirely sure is the $-(c-d) = +(-c-(-d))$ by the common sense it is true. However, I guess, this must be proved. The way the $-(c-d)$ is defined in book is $+(d-c)$. Hence,

Suppose, they are not equal, then:

$(d-c) \not= (0-c)-(0-d)$, but $(0-c)-(0-d) = (0-c)+(d-0) = d-c$, so they is a contradiction. They are indeed equal.

Here I use that $-x = (0-x), x \in Z$